# Python string matching and give repeated numbers for unmatched strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, nltk, counter

I have set of some words in `list1`:`"management consultancy services better financial health"`

```
user_search="management consultancy services better financial health"
user_split = nltk.word_tokenize(user_search)
user_length=len(user_split)
```

assign :management=1, consultancy=2,services=3 ,better=4, financial=5 ,health=6. 
Then compare this with set of some lists.

```
list2: ['us',
 'paleri',
 'home',
 'us',
 'consulting',
 'services',
 'market',
 'research',
 'analysis',
 'project',
 'feasibility',
 'studies',
 'market',
 'strategy',
 'business',
 'plan',
 'model',
 'health',
 'human' etc..]
```

So that any match occurs it will reflect on corresponding positions as 1,2 3 etc. If the positions are unmatched then the positions are filled with number 6 on words.
Expected output example:

```
[1]  7 8 9 10 11 3  12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 6 23 24
```

This means string 3 and 4, ie. services and health is there in this list(matched). Other numbers indicates the unmatched.`user_length=6`. So unmatched positions will starts from 7. How to get such a expected result in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to create a counter and iterate via `next`:

```
from itertools import count

user_search = "management consultancy services better financial health"
words = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(user_search.split(), 1)}

# {'better': 4, 'consultancy': 2, 'financial': 5,
#  'health': 6, 'management': 1, 'services': 3}

L = ['us', 'paleri', 'home', 'us', 'consulting', 'services',
     'market', 'research', 'analysis', 'project', 'feasibility',
     'studies', 'market', 'strategy', 'business', 'plan',
     'model', 'health', 'human']

c = count(start=len(words)+1)
res = [next(c) if word not in words else words[word] for word in L]

# [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 6, 23]
```